# Find the number of solutions for x if...

Tags: trigonometry

*Question*
Find the number of solutions in $[0,2π]$ such that$(\sin(2x))^4=(1/8)$

*My attempt*

I tried solving the question by equating $\sin(2x)$ to $y$
Therefore the equation becomes $y^4=1/8$ which had two real and two imaginary solutions. Since the range is in real numbers the equation has only two solutions. I then equated $\sin2x =y$ where $ y $ has two solutions so I concluded that there are two solutions for $x$. But then when I checked for the answer it was given as 8 solutions.can someone tell me where I went wrong and how I should approach the question.Thanks :)

Comment: `I then equated sin2x=y where y has two solutions so I concluded that there are two solutions for x` That would only be true if $\sin(2x)$ were injective on $[0,2\pi]\,$, which it is not. Each solution for $y$ gives $4$ solutions for $x$ in that interval.

Comment: Oh yeah that's true.Thanks :)

Comment: @dxiv But doesn't $x$ have only two solutions for each solution of $y$ in that interval

Comment: Mind the multipliers. $\sin(2x)=y$ has as many solutions on $[0,2\pi]$ as $\sin(x)=y$ has on $[0,4\pi]$.

Comment: Oh that's right :| .Thanks for clarifying :)